# Cannot injectScript in Custom Variable Template

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm trying to injectScript via Custom Variable Template (not tag).

Here is simplified code:

```
const log = require('logToConsole');
const setTimeout = require('callLater');
const setInWindow = require('setInWindow');
const copyFromWindow = require('copyFromWindow');
const copyFromDataLayer = require('copyFromDataLayer');
const injectScript = require('injectScript');

const pixelSend = function(eventType, eventParams, tries) { 
  // logic
  log('success')
};

log('event - ', copyFromDataLayer('event'));
if (copyFromDataLayer('event') === 'gtm.js') {
  injectScript('https://vk.com/js/api/openapi.js', // this one should create **"VK"** object in global scope, used to actually send the events
               pixelSend(), 
               data.gtmOnFailure); 
}

return true;
```

Unfortunately openapi.js never gets injected (checking in network tab) and thus VK object never gets created and I cannot use it.

If I just run in console:

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]
var js = document.createElement('script');
js.src = 'https://vk.com/js/api/openapi.js';
head.appendChild(js);
```

It gets injected and VK object becomes available.

What am I doing wrong?

Just in case:

```
queryPermission('inject_script', 'https://vk.com/js/api/openapi.js') = true
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, and there were just a few minor bugs - line 11 is missing a semicolon, and you did not mention if you allowed access to read the "event" key from the datalayer.

After that was fixed, the script worked as expected.

Obviously it will only work on the page view trigger (since this is the only case when event equals gtm.js. I probably would move the condition from the tag to the trigger).

Instead of "return true" you should end this will a call to data.gtmOnSuccess(), else you might have trouble using this tag in a tag sequence.

If in the template UI you hit the "run code" switch you will actually get information on all error in your code (alas one at a time, since execution stops at the first error). You can also write tests with mock input, for templates that require settings via input fields.